# Jmeter Connection to http://IP:8080 refused

Tags: jmeter, connection-timeout, connection-refused

I tested website performance with Jmeter 2.13, I have never used Jmeter before, When I set the number of thread is 500, it is OK, ans when set 750, there are some errors shows below. During the tests, my CPU ,bandwidth, memory,IO are not full.  I have tried other ways ,such as changing maxThread of tomcat7 and so on, but they did not work,  any help is appreciated!

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://10.0.0.160:8080 refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:107)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
... 14 more
```

Comment: Are you using any listeners? Are they showing request failures as well ? Was your machine able to create 500 users successfully ? You can track the number of threads being created on top right of JMeter GUI? You can track it to find the number where it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here.

1. Your server is not able handle the number of incoming connections from the same IP address. Check the size of connection pool and maximum incoming connections. Use some java tool like java melody to check total number of connections. Also check the thread-pool size and max thread settings.
2. Or It could be JMeter client issue. Try to run the test from two different load generators and split the load of 750. Client may not be able to establish socket connections for all the 750 users.